# Galaxy S GT 19000

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, downloading, device-firmware

Trying to download the firmware for my phone as it`s stuck in boot loop, tried all other options with no joy! On the Samfirware site , I have registered and got as far as the ready to dowload page, when I accept download the page tells me error 404 ....annoying is only the beginning, can anyone help me ?

Comment: Did you try this site : http://samsung-updates.com/gt-i9000-samsung-galaxy-s/

Comment: yes, that`s the site i was downloading from, but what is error 404?

Comment: Error 404 : Page not found. The page no longer exists. There are many similar sites whete you can download the firmware.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for [samsung-firmware](https://samsung-firmware.org/) is [sammobile](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/). I just downloaded a firmware from there. it's working.